# Rails create record if user created

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

If new user signs up, automatically create a job_app status for him. Whole database is on mysql, I have nothing connected with the issue in `User model` (only validation and `has_one` ) The problem is that the new record in job_apps with `user_id = current_user.user_id` does not create (sincerely I don't know how to do this).

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    include job_apps_helper
    def new
        @users = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save 
            session[:user_id] = @user.id 
            current_user = @user.id

            redirect_to '/status' 
        else 
            redirect_to '/signup' 
        end 
    end
    private
        def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :PESEL, :phone, :cv, :password)
        end
end


class JobAppsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_user, only: [:index]
    before_action :require_emp, only: [:empl]
    #def new 
    #   @job_app = job_app.new
    #end

    def index 
        @users = User.includes(:job_apps)
        end
        def empl
            @users = User.all.where(:user_type => 'candidate')
        end

    end
class JobApp < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user dependent: :create, :destroy
    enum status: [ :waiting, :accepted , :refused  ]
    def accept 
        self.update(status: 1)
    end
    def refuse
        self.update(status: 2)
    end
    end
end
```

And my routes:

```
root 'stat_page#home'
    get 'status' => 'job_apps#index'
    get 'stat_emp' => 'job_apps#empl'
    get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
    post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
    delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
    get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
    get 'signup' => 'users#new'
    resources :users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) on your User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :create_job_app

  def create_job_app
    JobApp.create(status: 0, user_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: but i got an issue with this - ruby says that after_save method does not exist/...

Comment: is it okay ? 
def create_job_app
  @job_app = self.jobapp.new(:user_id => current_user.id)
 end

Comment: Sorry this should be in the model not controller. Will update

Comment: If you are hoping for @job_app to be available in your controller/view I don't think it will just so you know.

Comment: @AntarrByrd unfortunately, i do not have any record on my mysql database after creating new user with your method/

Comment: @AntarrByrd ok i found a mistake. But then i have a question - how to set user_id: current_user.id ? i tried this way but it is not ok, also user_id: session[:user].id and user_id:  [@]user.id i got an error. I think i do not quite understand it maybe, but should I write another method to get user id after registration ?

Comment: @AntarrByrd also create or new gets back an error that method does not exists (undefined) although i have defined it